# Why installed CA isn't listed in trusted credentials on Android

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2

I am developing an app in Android (5.1 -> this device supports only this version) which communicate with server, for that I use Retrofit. I have my CA and I need to send it with my request to server.
But I have two problems:
1. I put my cert.p12 to Download folder on my device. Then I installed it: Security->Install from SD card. I received message that CA is installed, but it isn't listed in Trusted credentials->USER.
I use this code to list all installed CA in app:

```
try 
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
        if (ks != null) 
        {
            ks.load(null, null);
            Enumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
                Log.e(TAG, cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And my certificate isn't on that list either.
Any suggestions why that might be?

2. When I manage to install the certificate and it will be listed by code above will it be enough to just execute the code below to verify the client on the server side?:

```
try {

            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            if(keyStore != null){
                keyStore.load(null, null);    
                String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
                tmf.init(keyStore); 
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

                client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                    .build();           
            }

        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Best regards!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.